# Opengl draw to texture.. recursion?

Tags: opengl, recursion, textures

I' experimenting in draw to texture with opengl.

I've found this simple and clear c code that do that (see in the end).
It draws a cube on a texture, and then a cube on the screen using the previous texture. The generated image is a cube with, in the textures, a lot of cube inside a cube inside a cube etc..: it seems a recursion loop.

But why? I was expecting only 2 cubes. And It seems an infinite recursion loop.. where is the actual recursion? and when does it stops?

[image]

```
 /* ============================================================================
**
** Demonstration of rendering to texture
** Copyright (C) 2005  Julien Guertault
**
** This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
** modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
** as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
** of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
**
** This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
** but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
** MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
** GNU General Public License for more details.
**
** You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
** along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
** Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
**
** ========================================================================= */

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

#define     SIZE    256

static unsigned char texture[3 * SIZE * SIZE];
static unsigned int texture_id;
static int window_width = 500;
static int window_height = 500;


/*
** Just a textured cube
*/
void        Cube(void)
{
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);

  glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3f(-1, -1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3f(-1,  1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3f(-1,  1, -1);

  glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3f( 1, -1, -1);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3f( 1, -1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3f( 1,  1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3f( 1,  1, -1);

  glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3f(-1, -1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3f( 1, -1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3f( 1, -1, -1);

  glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3f(-1,  1, -1);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3f(-1,  1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3f( 1,  1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3f( 1,  1, -1);

  glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3f(-1,  1, -1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3f( 1,  1, -1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3f( 1, -1, -1);

  glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3f(-1, -1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3f(-1,  1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3f( 1,  1,  1);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3f( 1, -1,  1);

  glEnd();
}

/*
** Function called to update rendering
*/
void        DisplayFunc(void)
{
  static float alpha = 20;

  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
  glRotatef(alpha, 1, 0, 0);
  glRotatef(20   , 0, 1, 0);

  /* Define a view-port adapted to the texture */
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(20, 1, 5, 15);
  glViewport(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

  /* Render to buffer */
  glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  Cube();
  glFlush();

  /* Copy buffer to texture */
  glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, SIZE - 10, SIZE - 10);

  /* Render to screen */
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(20, window_width / (float) window_height, 5, 15);
  glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  Cube();

  /* End */
  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();

  /* Update again and again */
  alpha = alpha + 0.1;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

/*
** Function called when the window is created or resized
*/
void        ReshapeFunc(int width, int height)
{
  window_width = width;
  window_height = height;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

/*
** Function called when a key is hit
*/
void        KeyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  int foo;

  foo = x + y; /* Has no effect: just to avoid a warning */
  printf("%d",foo);
  if ('q' == key || 'Q' == key || 27 == key)
      exit(0);
}


int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* Creation of the window */
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
  glutCreateWindow("Render to texture");

  /* OpenGL settings */
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  /* Texture setting */
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SIZE, SIZE, 0, GL_RGB,
           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

  /* Declaration of the callbacks */
  glutDisplayFunc(&DisplayFunc);
  glutReshapeFunc(&ReshapeFunc);
  glutKeyboardFunc(&KeyboardFunc);

  /* Loop */
  glutMainLoop();

  /* Never reached */
  return 0;
}

/* ========================================================================= */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But why? I was expecting only 2 cubes. And It seems an infinite recursion loop.. where is the actual recursion? and when does it stops?

It's a feedback loop. Small experiment for you: Take a webcam connect it to your computer and let it show a live picture of the webcam. Now point the webcam on the screen so that it looks at the image it produced.

This is kind of what happens here: A cube with a texture is drawn. That picture is now copied to the texture. Then the cube is drawn again, but this time the texture already contains that cube so it's a cube with cubes on it. Also, for your pleasure the same cube is drawn to the screen, but that doesn't feed back.

If you want to have one nesting deep, you must disable texturing when drawing the cube that gets copied to the texture.

#### Update Code modification that doesn't recurse

```
void        DisplayFunc(void)
{
```

First render without texture so we don't feed back. Also make the drawing color black, so this will result in a solid black cube on black background.

```
  /* Render to buffer */
  glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); /* <<<<<< */
  glColor3f(0,0,0);         /* <<<<<< */
  Cube();
```

On a side note: For this there should really a frame buffer object be used, instead of relying on the back buffer to not be clobbered (overlapping windows may make it fail the pixel ownership test).

```
  /* Copy buffer to texture */
  glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, SIZE-10, SIZE-10);

  /* Render to screen */
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(20, window_width / (float) window_height, 5, 15);
  glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Reenable texturing and switch color to white so that we can see the texture (or use GL_REPLACE texture mode).

```
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glColor3f(1,1,1);
  Cube();

  /* End */
  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();

  /* Update again and again */
  alpha = alpha + 0.1;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: impressive.. i knew about video loop with webcam but i did't thought it was also for opengl..
so if I want 3 recursion loop? I mean one rotating cube with inside one rotating cube with inside one rotating cube and stop

Comment: @nkint: The recursion happens through the animation redraw and that the texture from the previous redraw iteration is reused. If you want a defined nesting level just don't use any data from the previous iteration. For example by not texturing for the first level of recursion.

Comment: so, for example, creating different texture.. ok quite clear, thanks